# Should here be interior operator instead of closure?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a nonempty set and $x\in X$ fixed. On $X$ we define the topology $\tau_x=\{\emptyset,X,\{x\}\}$. If $\emptyset \neq A\subseteq X,$ then $$cl(A)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} X; & x\in A\\ X\setminus \{x\}; & x\notin A\end{array}\right.$$

Sholud here be $int(A)$ instead of $cl(A)$, because I have no idea how to prove that $cl(\emptyset)=\emptyset$?

Comment: A clausule must be added. The sets $A$ with $x\notin A$ must be split up in non-empty and empty. As always the closure of $\varnothing$ is $\varnothing$ itself (the smallest closed set that contains $\varnothing$).

Comment: It is definitely not $\text{int}(A)$. In this context set $X\setminus\{x\}$ is in general not open, and every interior is open.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that $\operatorname{cl}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$ is true is not from the given formulae, because the given formula explicitly says that $A$ is non-empty (!). If you wanted to define the topology using the closure operation (checking the Kuratowski axioms for them), we 'd have to explicitly state that $\operatorname{cl}(\emptyset) = \emptyset$, plus the two clauses for the non-empty case depending on whether $x \in A$.

But $\emptyset$ is always closed as the complement of $X$, so the smallest closed subset containing $\emptyset$ is $\emptyset$, so this closure property is always true. (or note that a set is closed iff it equals its closure)

That the formula hold for non-empty $A$ is quite clear: both sets are the *only* non-empty closed sets, so as $A$ is non-empty, its closure must be one of the two. If $x \notin A$, then $A \subseteq X\setminus\{x\}$ which is then the smallest closed set that contains $A$. If $x \in A$, $A \nsubseteq X\setminus\{x\}$ so $X$ must be its closure, as $X\setminus\{x\}$ cannot be.

One can also look at the adherence points: any $p \neq x$ has one neighbourhood, namely $X$, and this only neighbourhood intersects any non-empty $A$, so all those $p$ are in the closure. If $x \notin A$, it's not added to the closure, as $\{x\}$ is then a neighbourhood of $x$ that misses $A$.